# Hyperledger: get "/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory" when running "./byfn -m up"

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I'm a newer for the hyperledger and just studying it by following the tutorials on http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io. I am trying to build the first network using "first-network" in the fabric-samples. The `./byfn -m generate` is OK. But after typing `./byfn -m up`, I meet

> /bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory

error and the process hangs.

What is going wrong?

PS: The OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Did you use GitBash for this or not?

Comment: I used the docker following the tutorial

Comment: Could you execute the following command: "docker ps -a"? It will show you how many and wich containers have you created. Moreover, could you post all the logs that you get when you execute that command? Are you sure that you have the file script.sh located in the directory fabric-samples/first-network/scripts/?

Comment: @weijia_wang you got any workaround?

Comment: Solution: I move to the Ubuntu, and everything is OK now. ;-) Anyway, many thanks to all of your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps :

1. In your docker terminal check the path `$HOME`. Type the command `echo $HOME`.
2. Make sure that your fabric-samples folder is the same path as of the variable `$HOME`.
3. Follow the [steps](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html) for generating your first network.

or try the below solution.

Follow these steps :

1. Go to settings of docker.
2. Click on reset credentials.
3. Now check if the shared drives include the required drives or not.
4. If not, then include them apply your changes and restart your docker and your bash where you were trying to start your network.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have a local firewall enabled. Depending on your docker configuration, a firewall may prohibit the docker daemon from accessing share drives as specified in docker setup (windows).

Restart the Docker daemon after applying local firewall changes.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and could resolve it.

The shared network drive needs to be working for any directory on the local machine to be identified from the container.

Docker for example has the "Shared drive" usually c:\ under which all your byfn.sh paths shall be present. Second condition is you need to be running the byfn.sh script with the same user who was authenticated to share the drives on the container. Your password change on the windows environment could break the already existing shared drives with the containers, hence creating problems in starting them.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but i have faced the similar issue so i did the following

1. ./byfn.sh -m generate
2. ./byfn.sh -m up

i was missing .sh in both commands.