# Bringing up the hyperledger network?

Tags: hyperlink, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

```
$ ./byfn.sh -m up
.
Starting with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10'

Continue (y/n)? y

proceeding ...

Starting peer1.org2.example.com ...

Starting peer1.org1.example.com ...

Starting peer0.org1.example.com ...



Starting peer0.org2.example.com ...

Starting peer0.org1.example.com ... done

Starting cli ... done

/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory

/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory

/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory

/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory

/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory
```

I get the above error on building up my first network ?
Kindly help.

(assuming fabric-samples folder is downloaded and the latest version 0.1.1 is installed, and no changes are made to any file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperledger: get "/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory" when running "./byfn -m up"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352547/hyperledger-get-bin-bash-scripts-script-sh-no-such-file-or-directory-whe)

Comment: What OS are you using?  Windows 7?  Windows 10?

Comment: @GariSingh my os is windows 7

Comment: My guess is that you cloned fabric-samples into a directory which is not available to be shared with Docker.  With Windows 7, only the users directory (typically C:\Users) is shared with Docker.  So you should make sure that you clone fabric-samples into a directory somewhere under C:\Users.  See the note here:  http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/samples.html